# Architecture for SignalR Hub that also consumes ClientWebSocket

Tags: websocket, signalr, signalr-hub

We want our SignalR Hub (`Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hub`) to be a middle-man of sorts; in addition to pushing and receiving messages to/from clients, it should consume messages from *a separate web socket server* using `ClientWebSocket`.  It processes those messages, then sends derived messages to clients via SignalR.

One problem is that the ClientWebSocket is injected and then configured in the constructor, but the constructor is called several times, which throws an error when trying to configure ClientWebSocket when it is already open.

Another problem is that when `ClientWebSocket.ConnectAsync` is called, SignalR no longer receives messages.

Is there a way to get these to work in the Hub?  Or do we have to design it differently to not use SignalR and ClientWebSocket in the same class?

Answer (score 1):

SignalR is a protocol over any transport. What that means is that you can connect with `ClientWebSocket` but you will need to manually write and parse the protocol messages. The protocol is documented at https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/SignalR/docs/specs/HubProtocol.md